# Creating an instance for a new type

Tags: haskell, types, point

I created a type in Haskell which represents a pixel, like so:

```
data Pixel = Pixel Float Float Int deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Here, the first float corresponds to the pixel's location on the x axis, the second float represents the location in the y axis (so basically I have 2 coordinates for it on the "screen") and the `Int` it's its grey value.

I wanted to create and instance of `Eq` for `Pixel` in which a pixel is equal to each other if their grey value is the same, regardless of its position.

So far I've done this:

```
instance Eq Pixel where
```

but now I don't know how to check if they're the same, I mean, how do I say I have 2 diferent Pixels here and I want to compare their `Int`? I can't do something like

```
grey1 == grey2 = True
```

'cause I don't know where `grey1` and `grey2` came from.

How can I do it?

Also when doing a instance for `Show`, how do I refer to the Floats and the Int?

Comment: You almost certainly do not want to define an `Eq` that only compares on one field, and it's very likely to lead to headaches later if you do anything even slightly complex with it.

Comment: BTW thing you defined looks more like "point" than "pixel". Pixel doesn't keep its position by itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
data Pixel = Pixel Float Float Int

instance Eq Pixel where 
    Pixel _ _ g1 == Pixel _ _ g2 = g1 == g2

instance Show Pixel where
    show ( Pixel  x y g ) = "Pixel " ++ show g ++ " at ("  ++ show x ++ "," ++ show y ++ ")"
```

Comment: thanks :D didn't know we could refer to the actual type in side the instance

Comment: @ipg24 We dont referring type. We referring one of it's constructors. Constructors serves two purposes - functions for creating data and pattern matchers. [Read more here about pattern matching](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching)

Answer (score 4):

Use *record syntax* instead!

```
data Pixel = Pixel {   xPos :: Float
                     , yPos :: Float
                     , value :: Int  
                     }
```

`xPos`, `yPos` and `value` have types `Pixel -> Float` and `Pixel -> Int` which will make some operations easier than pattern matching.

However, to make it an instance of appropriate classes it's sufficient (examples):

```
instance Show Pixel where
    show (Pixel x y g) = "[" ++ show x ++ ", " ++ show y ++ "(" ++ show g ++ ")]"

instance Eq Pixel where
    (Pixel _ _ valA) == (Pixel _ _ valB) = valA == valB
```

The same with record syntax actually used:

```
instance Show Pixel where
    show pixel = "[" ++ show (xPos pixel) ++ ", " ++ show (yPos pixel) ++ "(" ++ show (value pixel) ++ ")]"

instance Eq Pixel where
    a == b = (value a) == (value b)
```

You might need to modify the examples; they are just for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Thank you :D That's in fact an elegant solution

Comment: With this solution, you can write `on (==) value :: Pixel -> Pixel -> Bool` (`on` is from `Data.Function`) to compare two pixels using only their `value`s.

Answer (score 3):

What you'd like to do is *pattern match* on the constructor of `Pixel`. This is how you write functions which "pull apart" a type. Pattern matching happens using the `case` statement

```
case pixel of
  Pixel x y grey -> ...
```

Which, as syntax sugar, is also available directly in definitions

```
getX :: Pixel -> Double
getX (Pixel x y grey) = x

-- same as

getX :: Pixel -> Double
getX px = case px of
  Pixel x y grey -> x
```

So we do this twice to create an equality function

```
instance Eq Pixel where
  Pixel x1 y1 grey1 == Pixel x2 y2 grey2 = grey1 == grey2
```